# Is it possible to use DataTransfer.setData with an image type?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I am trying to enable an HTML canvas element to be dragged as an image into other applications (eg. the desktop). I am able to get the data URL of a canvas using its [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method, and have tried to set it as the canvas's drag data as follows:

```js
canvas.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("image/png", canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

By adding `draggable="true"` to the canvas element, I am able to drag the image from the page. When attempting to drop the image into an application, nothing happens.

I understand that the format of the data parameter I am passing in to the [setData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) function is likely incorrect, but I have been unable to find any relevant documentation.

Comment: At first glance code looks good, to troubleshoot something like this I would start with something simpler in the example they use `"text/plain"` try with that and some hardcoded text for the data, honestly I've never done drag from browser into other applications but I imagine that the other apps need something too

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to use the `dataTransfer.setData` since the output of the toDataURL is a base64 string, I'm using `dataTransfer.setData("text/plain"` and `dataTransfer.getData("text")`.

We can see in this example dragging into the "drop zone" works fine, also tested dragging into a text editor, it worked fine as well; all you need is code in the receiving app to know what to do with a base64 string.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('source');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
ctx.translate(50, 50);
delta = 0

function dragstart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", canvas.toDataURL())
}

function dragover(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.target.innerHTML = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
}

function draw() {
  delta++
  for (i = 11; i > 0; i--) {
    angle = i - delta
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (j = angle; j < angle + 360; j += 120) {
      a = j * Math.PI / 180
      ctx.lineTo(i * 8 * Math.sin(a), i * 8 * Math.cos(a));
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = (i % 2 == 0 ? "black" : "white");
    ctx.fill()
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 1000 / 24);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#source {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#target {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="source" ondragstart="dragstart(event);" draggable=true></canvas>
</div>
<div id="target" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="dragover(event);">
  Drop Zone
</div>
```